# Substitute single-page site in place of an existing Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, web, replace

I am self-hosting a couple of different domains and sites.  One of them is based on OpenCart as the ecommerce portion, and theme applied on top.  It's fairly complicated.

What I would like to do is temporarily replace that existing site for a single-page site.  What are the best practices to achieve this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new folder on your host containing an index.html file. Then tell your webserver to use that directory as the website root.